# Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project OR Data path "" must have required property 'lintFilePatterns'

Tags: angular, eslint, monorepo

After changing my project structure to a monorepo structure in Angular according to [this tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-multiple-apps-in-one-project/), I encountered numerous config bugs that I managed to squash after lots of troubleshooting.

The full error reads

```
Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project.

You should add a package that implements linting capabilities
```

A variation of this error reads

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:  
Data path "" must have required property 'lintFilePatterns'.
```

Both errors can be fixed with proper configuration of your `angular.json`.

Find the details to the fix below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The required config can be automatically added using:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

From [Angular ESLint README](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#readme)

Comment: doesn't work. running linter still gives same error.

Answer (score 9):

Go to `angular.json -> <your-projects-root-directory> -> <your-project-name> -> architect` and add or modify

```
"lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "<your-projects-root-directory>/<your-project-name>/src/**/*.ts",
              "<your-projects-root-directory>/<your-project-name>/src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
```

This tells the ng lint command which linter to use in the respective project (builder) and which files to lint (lintFilePatterns).

Typically your project root directory is named `projects`.
You might have to replace the `"builder"` property by another linter, if you use tslint for example. See your `package.json` for details.

Remember to set this for all your projects that are defined in `angular.json`.

Comment: I also had to add the lint configurations into each project directory.  To be precise, I had to add an .eslintrc file under each <your-projects-root-directory>/<your-project-name> directory.