# ng lint : fails with Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project

Tags: angular, eslint, ng

My angular version is 13.x

when i try to lint the files using `ng lint` i m getting the following results

```
Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project.

You should add a package that implements linting capabilities.

For example:
  ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

So i tried to add  `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics` but this throws the package already installed error

```
Skipping installation: Package already installed
    
    All @angular-eslint dependencies have been successfully installed 
    
    Please see https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint for how to add ESLint configuration to your project.
    
UPDATE package.json (4946 bytes)
```

Can somebody help me on this , i have spent hours on this

Comment: Do you add a lint section in your angular json? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311705/cannot-find-lint-target-for-the-specified-project-or-data-path-must-have-re

Comment: @Schrader Past it is working fine and there is no lint configuration ,this got stopped working after node_modules and package-lock.json delete